# How to get values from a php generated form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have some code for a PHP shopping cart which is as follow

```
if($cart->itemcount > 0) {
foreach($cart->get_contents() as $item) {
    echo "Code/ID :".$item['id']."<br/>";
    echo 'Quantity:<form method="post" action="cart.php"><input type="hidden" name="qtyid" id="qtyid" value="'.$item['id'].'"/><input type="submit" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"/>'.$item['qty'].'<input type="submit" name="plus" id="plus" value="+"/><br/></form>';
    echo "Price   :$".number_format($item['price'],2)."<br/>";
    echo "Info    :".$item['infos']."<br />";
    echo "Shipping :".$item['shipping']."<br />";
    echo "Subtotal :$".number_format($item['subtotal'],2)."<br />";
    echo '<form method="post" action="cart.php"><input type="hidden" name="removeid" id="removeid" value="'.$item['id'].'"/><input type="submit" name="remove" id="remove" value="Remove"/></form>';
    }
echo "---------------------<br>";
echo "total: $".number_format($cart->total,2);
} else {
echo "No items in cart";
}
```

I've been using jQuery Ajax to post the data to my php script and everything works fine when I've got one item:

```
        /********************************/
        /* Plus Item                   */
        /********************************/
        $('#plus').click(function()
            {
            var qtyid = $(this).val();
            var plus  = 'plus';

            $.ajax({
                url: 'cart.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'qtyid=' + qtyid + '&plus=' + plus,

                sucess: function (result) {
                    console.log('it worked');
                }

            })
            return false;
            })

        /********************************/
        /* Minus Item                   */
        /********************************/
        $('#minus').click(function()
            {
            var qtyid = $(this)).val();
            var minus  = 'minus';

            $.ajax({
                url: 'cart.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'qtyid=' + qtyid + '&minus=' + minus,

                sucess: function (result) {
                    console.log('it worked');
                }

            })
            return false;
            })
```

However, I'm having troubles when there are more than one product in the cart as, I guess, my code does not allow jQuery ajax to find where it should get the id from as the HTML generated does contain elements with the same ID.

```
</div>
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="imgid" id="imgid" value="YWNoZZeXk2htZmJjaWds">
    <input type="hidden" name="imgalb" id="imgalb" value="YWNoZZeVnGdtZmJjamlj">
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
</form>Code/ID :126264027457298<br/>
Quantity:
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="qtyid" id="qtyid" value="126264027457298"/>
    <input type="submit" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"/>
    9
    <input type="submit" name="plus" id="plus" value="+"/>
    <br/>
</form>
Price   :$55.85
<br/>
Info    :
Titre<br />
Shipping :6.00<br />
Subtotal :$556.65<br />

<form method="post" action="cart.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="removeid" id="removeid" value="126264027457298"/>
        <input type="submit" name="remove" id="remove" value="Remove"/>
</form>Code/ID :126265084123859<br/>
Quantity:
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="qtyid" id="qtyid" value="126265084123859"/>
    <input type="submit" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"/>
    2
    <input type="submit" name="plus" id="plus" value="+"/>
    <br/>
</form>
Price   :$25.85
<br/>
Info    :Boucles d'oreilles courtes «Conic»<br />
Shipping :6.00<br />
Subtotal :$63.70<br />
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="removeid" id="removeid" value="126265084123859"/>
    <input type="submit" name="remove" id="remove" value="Remove"/>
</form>

---------------------<br>total: $620.35
</div>
```

I have been spending hours trying to find a solution. But I feel it's time to ask for help.
What should I do? How should I alter my HTML to generate unique IDs and find a way to get the ids from jQuery and PHP?

Comment: before $.ajax in both jquery functions   .....alert( this.value )     it willl probably return a + or -.... this means data: 'qtyid=' + qtyid + '&minus=' + minus,  making the posted data qtyid=- &minus=minus   so you are not specifying the product id

Comment: No, it's time to narrow down your problem so that you can actually debug it. Actually, it was time to do that "hours" ago. :) There is just no way that you can debug this behemoth in one chunk, and that's probably why you've had no success. It's also why this is far too much code for a SO question. (And also SO is not a "help" site, but a site for questions about programming languages.)

Comment: Thanks Marabutt and Tomalak! I'm not used to code with PHP and Jquery and I wasn't sure where should I find a solution for my problem (modify the PHP to alter the generated HTML of Use a different selector in Jquery as proposed by Scrooby below). Tomalak, I have to admit that I find difficult to understand the difference between SO being a site for questions about programming languages and not a "Help" site as both seem tied to me. I guess this has to do with my question not being concise and clear enough. Could you suggest site that would be "Help" site about programming language. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just need to get the `qtyid` value associated with the plus/minus buttons you click. If that's the case, you should be able to get it using the following line:

```
var qtyid = $('#qtyid', $(this).parent('form')).val();
```

So an example of one of your click events would be:

```
$('#plus').click(function()
{
    var qtyid = $('#qtyid', $(this).parent('form')).val();
    var plus  = 'plus';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'qtyid=' + qtyid + '&plus=' + plus,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('it worked');
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Thanks Scrooby! I haven't tested your code yet, but you've been able to put down in 2 lines what I was unable to express clearly last night.

I'll give this a try and report back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is working just fine! I'll definitely have to find ressources to learn on Jquery as I'm sure this must seem like a very simple problem.Thanks again Scrooby. Particularly for taking the time to go through all the code above and putting in the energy to understand exactly what I was after!

Comment: Actually, I'm having the same probleme than before. If I add more than one article to the cart and try to update the quantity with the plus and minus button I stay on the same page if I click on the first article (and the Ajax is working). But when I click on the second item I'm taken to the PHP page that is processing the Ajax request. So I'm guessing this must be the return false that is preventing the button from submiting the form that is not working? Certainly because the id used in the $('#plus').click(function() is present 2 times in the HTML?

Comment: As you say it's because the click event is based on the ID. An ID should only occur once on a page. Because of this, the click event only takes effect on the first element with that ID. You should add this to your input: `class="plus"` and then change your JavaScript to the following: `$('.plus').click(function()` this will trigger the event on all elements.

Comment: Thanks Scrooby, you've been great! It seems so easy once you say it! ;o)